# setcookie() not working in an if statement

Tags: php, cookies

I'm designing a log in system as a personal project and I'm trying to store the user's email and password hash (should I store the plain text password instead?) in cookies so that the site knows what account the user is logged into.

The trouble is, as soon as I put my setcookie(); commands in an if statement, they stop working. I know the if statement is being reached because other code is being called from within it, but it's as if the setcookie() is being ignored.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$email = $_POST[email];
$password = $_POST[password];

$passwordHash = sha1($password);



$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "user";
$dbpass = "password";
$dbname = "db";


mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass)
or die("Error: Failed to connect to database");

mysql_select_db($dbname)
or die("Error: Failed to select databse");

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$email'";
$sql = mysql_query($query);

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {


    if($passwordHash == $r[passwordhash]) {


        setcookie("Email", $email, time()+3600);
        setcookie("PasswordHash", $passwordHash, time()+3600);


        echo "added cookie";

    }
    else {
        echo "Incorrect password";
    }
}



?>
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: Off topic, but you really need to use mysql_real_escape_string around all un-trusted variables in SQL statements. Otherwise your code will be susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: How do you verify the existence of the cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookie defined by setcookie is sent along with other headers (which must be sent before any output including whitespace). I think that the problem is here.
**UPDATE**
I'd try `header('Location: somepage.html')` instead of `setcookie` to make sure if it is the culprit.

Comment: I'm impressed. I edited out some echo statements that cluttered my code before posting it here. It turns out, that's what I needed to do to fix the problem. Yet, even with my unfaithful reproduction of the original problem-causing code, you managed to nail the issue.

Comment: :) I just had a similar problem in the past.

Answer (score 1):

**should I store the plain text password instead?**

**NO, NEVER, NO.** That would be a major security flaw, imagine i use your computer for a minute, if you are logged in and i check your cookies, i would have your password instantly.

Comment: +1 - this is a very bad practice. in fact, not even an ecrypted password should be sent to the user.

Answer (score -1):

Why aren't you using the session functions of PHP to just send the user a session ID instead of their login credentials? Additionally, your code suffers from multiple problems:

- `$_POST[email]` will throw a warning if no constant 'email' exists. You probably meant `$_POST['email']`.
- If magic_quotes are turned off, your SQL query is prone to SQL injections.

I would suggest changing the code like this:

```
<?php

$email    = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

$passwordHash = sha1($password);
$dbhost       = "localhost";
$dbuser       = "user";
$dbpass       = "password";
$dbname       = "db";

mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die("Error: Failed to connect to database");
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Error: Failed to select databse");

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."' LIMIT 1";
$sql   = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1) {
   $r = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

   if ($passwordHash == $r['passwordhash']) {
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $email;
   }
   else {
      echo "Incorrect password";
   }
}

?>
```